# show record of specific id from dropdown selection and show related record in html table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I want when user click on dropdown and select exam type. only a specific records related to that id will show in table.
I have two tables below are images.

[image]

```
<select name="exam_type_id">
         <option value="Select">Select</option>
    <?php 
         $result= new exam();
         $res=$result->selectExam();
          while($t=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
            { 
    ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $t['exam_type_id']?>">
            <?php echo $t['name']; ?></option> <?php }?>
        </select>
   </form>
      <div class="inside">
            <table width="605" height="70" border="2" bordercolor="#666666">
              <tr>
                <td><strong>Class Name</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Subject</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Start Date</strong></td>
                <td><strong>End Date</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Room No</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Add</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Edit</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Delete</strong></td>
              </tr>
        <?php 
             $result= new exam();
             $res=$result->selectExamAll();
             while($res1=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
             { ?>
               <td><?php echo $res1["className"]; ?> </td>
                <td><?php echo $res1["subject"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $res1["startDate"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $res1["endDate"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $res1["roomNo"]; ?></td>
                <td><a href="addExam.php"><img src="images/add.jpg" width="20" height="20"/></a></td>
                <td>
                  <a href="addExam.php">
                  <img src="images/add.jpg" width="20" height="20"/></a>
                </td>
                <td><a href="addExam.php"><img src="images/add.jpg" width="20" height="20"/></a></td>
              </tr> 
        <?php } ?>
            </table>
            <p class="p0">
            </p>enter code here
   </div>
```

*exam_type_id* is a foreign key in *exam_type* table. I am displaying exam type in dropdown from *exam_type* table. when user will click on dropdown data from exam_type table a specific data based on the selected id should show in html table.
*exam_type_id* is from *exam_type* table, its a foreign key in exam table.id will be from *exam_type* in dropdown and data will show from exam table in html table.

Comment: You are going to need to assign a change event listener on your select menu, then make your request (presumably) using Ajax, perform your query using the data (id) from the request, return the response and update your table.

Comment: will you provide any example?